# Best approach to additive collection mapping with Orika?

Tags: orika

Is it possible to define an additive mapping strategy for collections with Orika?

I am currently using a mixture of Orika and a custom implementation - however its not an approach that will scale very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually in Orika, you can define any merge strategy for collection all you have to do is to register a custom mapper between two collections
please take a look at this [unit test](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/community/CustomMergerTest.java#L157) .